# Blank space above Stepper in Flutter CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently working on a screen that includes a Flutter Stepper within a CustomScrollView. There is a SliverAppBar and the Stepper is wrapped in a SliverToBoxAdapter and a Padding. Unfortunately, there is a blank space above the Stepper that doesn't seem to belong to the Padding or the Box Adapter. If I add the Stepper to a normal Scaffold, this space is not visible. Please see the attached screenshots. Does anyone know how to solve that? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            snap: false,
            floating: false,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            expandedHeight: 250,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20), bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(...),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Stepper(...),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here are some screenshots:

[Screen Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P4Qx.png)

[Screen Layout with Debug Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU1pN.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read about this in another thread just with a ListView instead of a Stepper. The solution is to wrap the Stepper with MediaQuery.removePadding(...) and set the removeTop attribute to true.

```
SliverPadding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeTop: true,
      child: Stepper(...)
    )
  )
)
```